# Why is this format function showing error?

Tags: python

This is a hackerrank problem. dec, octa, hexa, Bin are all string variables.
[Hackerrank Problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-string-formatting/problem?isFullScreen=true)

```
def print_formatted(number):
    
    lenth = len(bin(number)) - 3
    space = " "
    t = lenth-1
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        dec = str(i)
        
        octa = str(oct(i).replace("0o",""))
        
        hexa = str(hex(i).replace("0x",""))
        
        Bin = str(bin(i).replace("0b",""))
        
        print("{:>t} {:>t} {:>t} {:>t}".format(dec,octa,hexa,Bin))
        
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    print_formatted(n)ere
```

The problem is with spacing between the values as it will change depending on the input and the length of the longest binay value.

Comment: the line`print_formatted(n)ere` seems to be syntactically wrong. that's why you are getting an error

Comment: Let's assume then that the code works well and does not need any fix.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki: Yes, that's a good assumption to start with, except the OP reports something about spacing. However, I've tried running the code and I get an error, so we need the OP to clarify first.

Comment: what error? You should show error in question (not in comments) as text (not image). Don't expect that we will run code to see error. Besides code may works correctly on our computers.

Comment: File "Solution.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "Solution.py", line 15, in print_formatted
ValueError: Unknown format code t for object of type 'str'

Comment: my bad , I am kinda new to this site. 
Yes the ere was added by the site and isn't is the code

Comment: @YUVRAJ, then [edit] your question and fix the code. Questions like this should include a [mre], which others must be able to copy-paste and run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this with f-string formatting is straightforward:

```
def print_formatted(number):
    m = len(f'{number:b}')
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        print(f'{i:{m}} {i:{m}o} {i:{m}X} {i:{m}b}')

print_formatted(17)
```

**Output:**

```
 1     1     1     1
 2     2     2    10
 3     3     3    11
 4     4     4   100
 5     5     5   101
 6     6     6   110
 7     7     7   111
 8    10     8  1000
 9    11     9  1001
10    12     A  1010
11    13     B  1011
12    14     C  1100
13    15     D  1101
14    16     E  1110
15    17     F  1111
16    20    10 10000
17    21    11 10001
```

**Note:**

There are leading spaces that are not formatting properly here.
Requires Pypy3 / Python3

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean that you wanted to generate a different format string depending on the length of the binary of the input number?

```py
def print_formatted(number):
    
    lenth = len(bin(number)) - 3

    t = lenth-1
    fmt = ' '.join(['{:>' + str(t) + '}'] * 4)

    for i in range(1, number+1):
        dec = str(i)
        
        octa = str(oct(i).replace("0o",""))
        
        hexa = str(hex(i).replace("0x",""))
        
        Bin = str(bin(i).replace("0b",""))
        
        print(fmt.format(dec, octa, hexa, Bin))
```